# mongoose findById returns null and the id was stored as an object id in the db

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here is my schema, I did not define the _id field so it is created by mongoose and its type is ObjectId, that is how it appears in robo3T

```
/*  
  Copyright (c) 2020 Antonio Roldan 
  All rights reserved 
*/


import mongoose, { Schema } from 'mongoose'
import { IAlbum } from '../interfaces/IAlbum'

const albumSchema = new Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 1,
    trim: true
  },
  authorId: { // We create an array to allow collaborations
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
  },
  authorName: {
    type: String
  },
  coverUrl: { // Reference to album's image file stored in a gridFS collection
    type: String
  },
  genres: [{
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  }],
  releaseDate: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  isPremium: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  }
})

export default mongoose.model < IAlbum > ('Album', albumSchema)
```

And here is where I make the call, note I am passing a string instead of an ObjectId, I tried with an objectId and it still didn't work

```
public getAlbumTracks(albumId: string): Promise<any> {
        //TODO: Test this 
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      try{
        let albumData: any = {} // {album: {title: , author:, cover: }, tracks: [{title: , audio: }]}
        const albumDocument = await this.albumModel.findById(albumId)
        console.log('albumDocument :', albumDocument)
        const author = await this.userModel.findById(albumDocument.authorId)
        const albumTracks = await this.trackModel.find({album: albumDocument._id})
        albumData.tracks = albumTracks.map(track => {
          return {title: track.title, audio: track.trackUrl, isPremium: track.isPremium}
        })
        albumData.album = {title: albumDocument.title, author: author.username, cover: albumDocument.coverUrl}
        resolve(albumData)
      } catch(err) {
        reject({code: 500, msg: err.message || err.msg})
      }
    })
  }
```

Comment: add this line, after requiring mongoose.

mongoose.set('debug', true);

this will print  the actual mongo query being fired by below line.

const albumDocument = await this.albumModel.findById(albumId);

The share the query being fired. It will help in debugging.

Answer (score -1):

You need to convert the input id, which is a string, to ObjectID by parsing it as a parameter to the ObjectId function.
Here's a sample with mongoose.

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose'); 
    var id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(stringId);
```

You can then proceed to use `id` in `findById(id)`